# Would every Roman army have dedicated engineers?

Tags: military, ancient-rome, roman-empire, siege, engineering

Would a Roman army have dedicated engineers to design and build the siege engines (onagers, scorpions etc)? Would the engineers be expected to fight?

Personally, I am particularly interested in what was done around the time of the 2nd Punic war. But if someone provided an answer that described how things changed with military reforms, it would definitely be worth a bounty.

Comment: Not having looked into it yet, I'd think the answer would be likely to depend on what era of Roman army we are talking about. Other than that qualm, this is a very good question.

Comment: ["Camp construction were the responsibility of special engineering units to which specialists of many types belonged, officered by architecti (engineers), from a class of troops known as immunes since they were excused from or, literally, immune from, regular duties."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_military_engineering#Engineering_siege_machines)

Comment: You had better be prepared to defend your Siege Engine....so the simple answer is yes, they were "not immune" if the Roman Legion suddenly collapsed. In the case of Julius Caesar he built an entire fortress during his conquest of Gaul...a very interesting way to defeat an enemy actually. The USA did much the same thing as it moved West in the 1800's.

Comment: Yes, I do think you need to be more specific as it would depend upon the era. The "Roman Army" as a whole with it's constituent legions would have dedicated engineers during the principate but the republican era army would have been on a more ad hoc basis.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As the comment above indicates, the Roman army before Julius Caesar's time seems to have had a dedicated engineer corps, but this group would also be expected to fight if necessary.  From Julius Caesar's rule onward, the Roman army retained a dedicated engineering officer or senior engineer called the Praefectus Fabrum, who could call upon specially trained or skilled legionaries to lead troops in construction tasks, which included the creation of roads, fortifications, siege engines and certain weapons.

Because Roman Army doctrine called for fortified camps to be constructed at the end of every day's march, which included defensive works, every legionnaire and auxiliary became, over time, an engineer by default.  An interesting result of having most troops engage in  building activities is discipline: busy troops, tired from marching and building, were less likely to mutiny, a constant threat in the politically-charged atmosphere in almost every Roman legion.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they had dedicated engineers for siege engines and works. Simple fortifications were handled by the legionnaires, but more complicated efforts had specialists.

No, not every army had them.

A specific example is Julian's army intended to attack Ctesiphon. In interest in speed, and because he did not believe Ctesiphon had walls, Julian did not take any engineers. Between the lack of any way to break the walls, and with the bulk of the Persian army marching their way, Julian was forced to abandon his attempt to sack Ctesiphon and attempt to get his army back to Roman territory.